# WiFi and Lan Network is not working - Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, networking, wireless, network-manager

I have a problem with my network connection. I have been using the same laptop with Ubuntu for more than a year, and suddenly yesterday all the connections stopped working (both wireless and wired).

If I connect using both wireless or wired, It stops all connections which are connected using wireless or wired. Is there any network settings for resolve this issue?

Please help to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.